# Make HTML divs resize and scrollable

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a `<div>` element, such that:

- It resizes its width until it reaches a certain width.
- After it has reached its width, a scrollbar should be shown to show additional content.

If possible, this should be done by css alone.

**Example**

The div contains the text foo and and the 3 letters fit into the div's max-width size:

```
/-----\
| foo |
\-----/
```

The div contains the text foobar and and the 6 letters fit into the div's max-width size - so it resizes:

```
/--------\
| foobar |
\--------/
```

The div contains the text foobarfoobarfoobar, but the 18 letters doesn't fit into the div's max-width size - so it resize to its maximal width and shows a scrollbar:

```
/-------------\
| foobarfooba |
+-------------+
| {Scrollbar} |
\-------------/
```

**What I tried so far:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    border: 1px solid;  /* to show div size */
    overflow: auto;     /* to add scrollbars for overlong texts */
    width: 0px;         /* default width */
    max-width: 250px;   /* maximal width */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- works, scrollbar will be shown -->
    <div>asdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjkl</div>
    <!-- width is wider than it has to be (at least in Firefox) -->
    <div>asdfghjklasdfghjkl</div>

</body>
</html>
```

but this doesn't work, because the width property is overwritten by the max-width property (see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp). So how can such a thing be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of specifying the `width` of `<div>`-elements, you could change their display type to `inline-block` or `float` them to a side, so that they would shrink to fit their contents.

For instance:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;  /* to show div size */
  overflow: auto;     /* to add scrollbars for overlong texts */
  /* width: 0px; */   /* default width */
  max-width: 250px;   /* maximal width */

  float: left; clear: left; /* or try display: inline-block instead */
  white-space: nowrap;      /* optional */
}
```

```html
<div>asdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjkl</div>
<div>asdfghjklasdfghjkl</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic sint excepturi adipisci officia eius dolore numquam? Error, non, aliquid. Laudantium ipsa est, corporis alias nesciunt, molestias aspernatur doloribus saepe dolorem!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

quant, i wonder how about using a function to calculate the string length inside your custom div and later return the calculated width to dynamically re-assign back to the custom div width attribute.

Comment: Of course this would be the other way of doing it. And I have already done similar things. However such code is very nasty to write, since the div may not only contain text but other content too. Also the size may differ due to text-size/text-family/... properties - so you may have unpredicted side effects with certain font properties. (I know of the workaround to read the div size the browser calculated and then check whether to resize). I prefer CSS; It is better tested, than selfmade functions.

Comment: i understand your concern yup it doesn't fit for extensible solution.